# Rails asterisk/"*" not appearing in one label of a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, actionview

**Situation**

Have a simple form which abstract parts i post below:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :net %>
    <div class="input-group  w-50">
      <%= f.text_field :net,
        required: true,
        class: 'form-control text-right' %>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text" style="width: 40px;">€</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

&

```
<div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :vat_rate, t('in_invoice.form.vat_rate') %>
            <%= render 'home/shared/standard_vat'  %>
            <div class="input-group w-50">
              <%= f.text_field :vat_rate,
                               required: true,
                               class: 'form-control text-right' %>
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text" style="width: 40px;">%</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

with model:

```
    ...

  validates :net, :number, :vat_rate, presence: true
  validates :net, numericality: { greater_than: 0}
  validates :vat_rate, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0}
  validates :net, numericality: true

    ...
```

**My problem**
I want to put an asterisk on the `vat_rate` (Screenshot: "VAT-Rate in %") label in the form. But for some reason it appears only on the `:net` and the `:number` field despite making them equal (e.g. removing the partial in between, includind presence validation) as you can see on the screenshot[image: form]. (I think it doesn't matter but the form is a `simple_form` initialized with `simple_form_for`)

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk is added by simple form. When you pass text as a second argument you override everything. If you want to keep the `*` pass text as an option:

```rb
<%= f.label :vat_rate, label: t('in_invoice.form.vat_rate') %>
#                      ^^^^^^
```

*https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/v5.3.0/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L319*

---

If your `simple_form` doesn't look like this, you're missing the point of simple form:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @invoice do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :net %>
  <%= f.input :vat_rate %>
<% end %>
```

You should configure your inputs only once and just use `input` helper:

*https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/tree/main#configuration*

For example:

```rb
# config/initializers/simple_form.rb

module InputGroup
  def append(wrapper_options = nil)
    template.content_tag(:span, options[:append], class: "input-group-text")
  end
end
SimpleForm.include_component(InputGroup)

SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  # https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form-bootstrap
  config.wrappers :group, tag: "div", class: "form-group", error_class: "form-group-invalid", valid_class: "form-group-valid" do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label

    b.wrapper :input_group_tag, tag: "div", class: "input-group-append" do |ba|
      ba.use :input, class: "form-control", error_class: "is-invalid", valid_class: "is-valid"
      ba.optional :append
    end

    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: {tag: "div", class: "invalid-feedback d-block"}
    b.use :hint, wrap_with: {tag: "small", class: "form-text text-muted"}
  end
end
```

```
<%= simple_form_for @invoice do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :net,      wrapper: :group, append: "€" %>
  <%= f.input :vat_rate, wrapper: :group, append: "%" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

so to summarize: "required: true/false[DEFAULT]" is an option of the label tag which I overwrote by setting a label. Removed the label and now it works. Setting it worked too but wanted less code :-)